# enforcing max length condition on form submit submit with text input field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a simple form validation to enforce the maxlength conditions initialized in the input tags. The idea is to pass those values into a json. Without the validation it works beautifully. But with the validation not so much :-(

Here is my JS

```
$.fn.serialized = function () {
    var objectModel = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (objectModel[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!objectModel[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            objectModel[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            objectModel[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return objectModel;
};



var x = $('input').val().length;
var y = $('input').attr('maxlength');

$('form').submit(function () {
    $('input').each(function () {
        if (x <= y) { // trying to check for condition to validate.Not working :-(
            $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serialized()));
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('invalid input')
        }
    });
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/HuYbG/8/

Comment: How would you type more characters in the input when the maxlength attribute stops you from doing so ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HuYbG/9/

Comment: @adeneo--that makes my question null..what a bummer. I should have thought about it little bit more before posting this like a dummy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Don't forget to do server-side length validation too. Malicious actors can post content with any length.